# setText on TextViews created using a for loop - android

Tags: android, android-layout, for-loop, textview

I have created a set of TextViews programmatically using a for loop. This what i have tried.

```
for(int i=1; i<5; i++){

    valueTV = new TextView(AddMyVehicle.this);
    linearLayout.addView(valueTV);

    vehicleModelReturned = myVehicleData.getString("VehicleModel"+x, "");
    valueTV.setText(vehicleModelReturned);
    valueTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    valueTV.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,22);
    valueTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));

    i++;
 }

    this.valueTV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            valueTV.setText("Hello");
        }
    });
```

I need to change the text of clicked TextView to "Hello". How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a listener to all your TextView created.

And be careful, you incremented `i` twice : one in the first line of the for and another one in the end of the for.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {

            final TextView valueTV = new TextView(AddMyVehicle.this);
            linearLayout.addView(valueTV);

            vehicleModelReturned = myVehicleData.getString("VehicleModel" + x, "");
            valueTV.setText(vehicleModelReturned);
            valueTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            valueTV.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
            valueTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
            valueTV.setId("test");
            valueTV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) v;
                    tv.setText("Hello");
                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

First, set the `OnClickListener` to all the `TextView`s you create, not just the last one. That is, move the `setOnClickListener()` inside the `for` loop.

Second, in `onClick()`, change the text of the clicked view and not again the last one you created. The `View v` param is the view that was clicked. You can cast it to `TextView`.